# pure-poa is bigger that mixed-pos?

Tags: game-theory

generally it's true that Pure price of anarchy is >= mixed price of stability.
but I just find cases where they are equal and I can't think of a case of strict inequality.

can you help me please?

thanks (:
benny.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following two-player game
$$\begin{matrix}& L & R \\ T & 1,1 & 0,0\\ B & 0,0 & n,n\end{matrix}.$$
The game has two Nash equilibria: $(T,L)$ and $(B,R)$; the price of stability is 1 (as $(B,R)$ is a socially optimal strategy), whereas the price of anarchy is $\frac{1}{n}$.